# Conflicts between 2 unit tests c# using a static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, conflict

I have conflicts between some of my unit tests.
I have a class with a static event, when I run each test one at a time I have no problem, but when I run all tests in a batch, the tests which are firing the event will crash because of the registred listeners (which have registred to the event in the previous tests).

Obviously I don't want the event handlers to be executed when the tested class fires the event, so what is the best solution ?

I know I wouldn't have the problem if the event was not static, but I would prefer not have to redesign this if there is another solution.

Detaching all the event listeners before running the test could be a solution, but I think it is impossible to do it from outside of the class (which seems normal cause we don't want a client being able to detach all other listeners), and doing it from the inside would means that I have to add a method in the class for the only purpose of the unit tests, which is as bad practice.

Is there a way to run the test in an isolation mode that would prevent other previous tests to impact it ? Like if it was run in a completely separated process so that I don't get the same reference to the static event ? (But I still need to be able to executes all tests in batch with a simple click)

Thanks for your help and ideas !

For information I am using Visual Studio 2012 unit test framework.

Comment: Can you post some code? You application should, in general, clean up after itself and detach event handlers. The same goes for tests.

Comment: Ok, so everywhere I attached to an event, I should detach from that event in the class destructor ?
It could work, but the problem is that the class listening to the static event is also static, can I explicitely call a static class destructor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere within each individual test you are going to attach yourself to the static event. So simply **before** the assert simply detach yourself **or better** guard the detaching within a finally block:

```
[TestCase]
public void MyTestDetachingBeforeAssert()
{
    bool finishedCalled = false;
    var eventListener = new EventHandler((sender, e) => finishedCalled = true);

        MyClass.Finished += eventListener;
        // Can lead to detach problems if this throws an exception!
        MyClass.DoSomething();
        MyClass.Finished -= eventListener;

        Assert.That(finishedCalled);
}

[TestCase]
public void MyTestDetachingInFinally()
{
    bool finishedCalled = false;
    var eventListener = new EventHandler((sender, e) => finishedCalled = true);

    try
    {
        MyClass.Finished += eventListener;
        MyClass.DoSomething();

        Assert.That(finishedCalled);
    }
    finally
    {
        MyClass.Finished -= eventListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the event handler is attached in a method from the inside of the class, i'm not attaching it in the test method, so i cannot detach it in the test method.

Comment: @JonathanBolduc: Maybe should the class have a `Dispose()` method (or better implement `IDisposable`) where it detaches itself from the event. Then you could call the `Dispose()` method within the test to detach it.

Comment: @Olivier: Yes, this is precisely what I did to solve the problem, thanks !

Comment: @Jonathan: Reminder: If an answer helped, you should upvote it. And/Or if it solved your problem you should accept it. ;-)